# How to compile universal binary with 2 architectures o Mac OS X?

Tags: macos

If i make a project with XCode i can compile it to both 32bit and 64bit.
Is it possible to compile Apache this way too? So it will work on both architectures? Make it a universal binary with these 2 architectures?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why Apache? OS X already has Apache installed.

Comment: [This](http://www.entropy.ch/blog/2006/05/12/Universal-Binary-Apache-2-configure-Line.html) seems to hint it may be possible. Though that was compiled on 10.4.

Comment: And why would it need to be 64 bit anyway ? Why not just run the 32 bit version regardless of host architecture ?

Comment: Well i am on 64 bit, can i compile it for 32bit?

Comment: I need to compile it as i want to make a MAMP like application so i need to bundle somehow Apache, PHP, MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just build the two architectures and then use [lipo](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/lipo.1.html) to combine them into a fat binary.